# Stored procedure not deleting the records from db2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  WRK.PURGE_ACH_BATCH_TAB_1()
LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN
    -- Declare cursor
    DECLARE v_CNT_BLOCK INTEGER;
    DECLARE Ac_no BIGINT;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000'; 
    DECLARE mycur cursor for 
        SELECT t.TNX_Ac_no
        FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 c
            INNER JOIN WRK.BATCH_TAB t
                ON c.BATCH_ID = t.BATCH_ID
                    AND c.PROCESS_ID = t.process_ID
        WHERE c.BATCH_START_TS < (CURRENT DATE -7 days); 

    set v_CNT_BLOCK = 0;
    open mycur;

    FETCH FROM mycur INTO Ac_no;
    WHILE(SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
        DELETE FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 b WHERE b.TNX_Ac_no = Ac_no;
        SET v_CNT_BLOCK=v_CNT_BLOCK+1;
        if v_CNT_BLOCK >= 5 then
            set v_CNT_BLOCK = 0;
            commit;
        end if;

        FETCH FROM mycur INTO Ac_no;  

    END WHILE; 

    CLOSE mycur; 

    commit; 

END
@
```

I have 19 records in db2 table to satisfy the condition which is assigned to cursor, am getting success command after execute this but none of the value has got deleted from db. Please help where am I missing something.

Comment: Why is this tagged Oracle?  This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Oracle.

Comment: Note that the cursor, which is declared without the `WITH HOLD` clause, will be closed after the first commit.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to delete from the same table the cursor is reading from.  Depending on the isolation level you are running under, it's likely your getting locking errors.

In your sample code, there doesn't appear to be any reason to use a cursor in the first place.  You should just delete the set.

```
DELETE 
FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB t
               WHERE c.BATCH_ID = t.BATCH_ID
                 AND c.PROCESS_ID = t.process_ID
             )
AND c.BATCH_START_TS < (CURRENT DATE -7 days);
```

Given the correction to the correlation in the comments:

```
DELETE 
FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB t
               WHERE c.BATCH_ID = t.BATCH_ID
                 AND c.PROCESS_ID = t.process_ID
                 AND t.BATCH_START_TS < (CURRENT DATE -7 days)
             );
```

Alternatively, if you must use a cursor for reasons not apparent in your example, you should be looking at the "positioned form" of the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 WHERE CURRENT OF CURSOR mycur;
```

Deletes the record the cursor just returned.  Of course, it wouldn't work with your original cursor do to the use of `INNER JOIN`.  But if you used the `WHERE EXISTS` syntax from my answer above the positioned delete would be an option.

Comment: Hi charles.. why am going with cursor.. my table has many transaction.. so i want to delete few records and have to commit it right away... and want to proceed with next level of records.

Comment: U mean to say.. we cant use inner join with cursor.

Comment: DELETE 
FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB t
               WHERE c.BATCH_ID = t.BATCH_ID
                 AND c.PROCESS_ID = t.process_ID
             )
AND t.BATCH_START_TS < (CURRENT DATE -7 days);  .. the batch_start_ts from BATCH_TAB table actually... it doesnt have scope when i used ur delete

Comment: Should just be able to move it into the EXISTS clause. Edited my answer to show this.   As far as the inner join, no I mean you can't use a cursor that has a join with a positioned delete.

Comment: charles., can u help to handle this query dynamically DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM WRK.BAH_T c WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM WRK.BAH_C t WHERE c.BAH_ID = t.BAH_ID
 AND c.PID = t.pID
AND VARCHAR_FORMAT (c.BAH_START_TS,''YYYY-MM-DD'')) < ''P_DATE'' with ur FETCH FIRST ''N'' ROWS ONLY);

Comment: Here am passing two varaibles P_DATE and N dynamically for store procedure input., this delete query am running inside the store proc.

Answer (score 1):

On a sufficiently recent DB2 version you should be able to do something like this:

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
 loop1: WHILE SQLSTATE = '00000' DO
  DELETE FROM (
   SELECT FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 c
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB t
               WHERE c.BATCH_ID = t.BATCH_ID
                 AND c.PROCESS_ID = t.process_ID
                 AND t.BATCH_START_TS < (CURRENT DATE -7 days)
   ) FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
  );
  IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN -- not found
   LEAVE loop1;
  END IF;
  COMMIT;
 END WHILE;
END@
```

Comment: Hi Musta... I need to pass days or date and No of records dynamically...with the above case...  DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB1 c
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WRK.BATCH_TAB t
               WHERE c.BATCH_ID = t.BATCH_ID 
                 AND c.PROCESS_ID = t.process_ID
               AND VARCHAR_FORMAT(c.BAdate,''YYYY-MM-DD'') < pDATE  with ur) FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY);

Comment: am trying to pass date pDATE and N from store proc Input Params.. can u help me to edit this.